# Looking for a digital copy of the book "Things Catholics are Asked About"

Tags: catholicism, resource-request

In 1927, the publisher P.J. Kenedy & Sons published the book "*Things Catholics are Asked About*"  which has 37 chapters.

Given the 1927 publishing date, I strongly suspect that the book is now in the public domain but I have not been able to find an archived PDF copy from a website in the Internet.  About 10 years ago I found a website which has an online digital edition with a 1999 copyright by Michael A. Gallagher. The web page had 37 chapter buttons, whereupon clicking on one of them caused the entire chapter to appear. But I have no longer been able to find that site.

It seems that I can obtain a used printed copy of the book [here](https://www.marys-usedbooks.com/product/25263/THINGS-CATHOLICS-ARE-ASKED-ABOUT) but I prefer a digital version, if it exists.

QUESTION: Does anyone know where I may obtain a digital copy of "*Things Catholics are Asked About*" by Fr. Martin J. Scott, S.J., originally published in 1927 by P. J. Kenedy & Sons?

Comment: It seems that Refuge of Sinners Publishing, Inc. has reprinted it in 2011 so possibly renewed the copyright. Also, a 1999 copyright would still be valid.

Comment: @Dan That is on Amazon with no "look inside." Likely, if they have a copyright at all, it is a copyright on the typesetting, not on the content. Besides, it seems that the book is out of print as only two used copies are available. https://www.amazon.com/Things-Catholics-Are-Asked-About/dp/B006LQKK8Y

Comment: [Chapter XVIII "The Mass"](https://www.catholicfidelity.com/apologetics-topics/mass/the-mass/) is online.

Comment: Many thanks @Geremia. 36 more to go:)

Comment: @Dan Reference-request is a tag on this site; also, the book was published by P. J. Kenedy & Sons in 1927, which was a Baltimore and New York publishing company since the 19th century. Hence, the book being published in America, and, more than 95 years elapsing from the original publication---puts it in the public domain. Non-typographical copyright, therefore, should not be a concern.

Comment: @mlchristians cool, I was not aware that these are on topic. I have a few questions of my own if that's the case! haha

Comment: @Dan 123 questions are tagged [\[resource-request\]](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resource-request) so far.

Comment: I retracted my close vote

Comment: Many thanks @Dan

Comment: I've now asked [my own resource request question](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/94082/1304) (now that I know this is on topic here) :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [**this web archive**](https://web.archive.org/web/20051018054839/http://mafg.home.isp-direct.com/cquescnt.htm) of http://mafg.home.isp-direct.com/cquescnt.htm

> Copyright © 1927 P.J. Kenedy & Sons
> Online Digital Edition Copyright © 1999 by Michael A. Gallagher

[EPUB version](https://isidore.co/calibre/get/EPUB/9427)

Comment: Many, many thanks for finding this.