# Seeking full text of St. John Chrysostom's homily "On the Cemetery's Name and the Cross"

Tags: eastern-orthodox, church-fathers, resource-request, sermon

I became aware of a homily by St. John Chrysostom entitled "On the Cemetery's Name and the Cross" from [a blog post](https://www.johnsanidopoulos.com/2011/05/st-john-chrysostoms-homily-on-cemetery.html) by John Sanidopoulos. In the post, Sanidopoulos indicates that this sermon "has yet to be translated into the English language...." He further states that

> The actual title of the sermon could be something like, "Why A Cemetery Is Named Thus." This homily is traditionally read during the services for the Tuesday of St. Thomas because it was originally delivered on this day.

Sanidopoulos is a Greek Orthodox Christian, and so is referring to this liturgical tradition in the above quote.

The [a blog post](https://www.johnsanidopoulos.com/2011/05/st-john-chrysostoms-homily-on-cemetery.html) goes on to cite some excerpts from the homily, translated into English (presumably by Sanidopoulos).

I received assistance from a Logos Library Specialist back in 2020 to find out if the work was available in Logos Bible Software, and she informed me that it is not (thanks again, Katy Smith!). She was able to find it translated into Russian in:

"Sermon on the Cemetery and the Cross," *Works of our Holy Father John Chrysostom, Archbishop of Constantinople, in Russian Translation*, Vol. II, Book I, p. 431. St. Petersburg: St. Petersburg theological Academy, 1896.

At that time, the book was available on eBay for purchase, but was cost-prohibitive for me and [the link](https://www.ebay.com/i/223558593081?chn=ps&norover=1&mkevt=1&mkrid=711-117182-37290-0&mkcid=2&itemid=223558593081&targetid=916015721030&device=c&mktype=pla&googleloc=9033356&poi=&campaignid=9343998885&mkgroupid=103102746908&rlsatarget=pla-916015721030&abcId=1139336&merchantid=6296724&gclid=EAIaIQobChMIvqiznaSv6gIVVh6tBh14OAeqEAYYASABEgK_wPD_BwE) is now dead (and was not archived on archive.org).

I am looking for this sermon, ideally in Greek, but translated into any language is fine.

Comment: Interesting question. Here's something that may be of use for now. https://brill.com/view/journals/vc/76/1/article-p1_1.xml?language=en , Hope to look into it a little later.

Comment: According to the abstract contained in the above link, the article presents the homily in both Greek and English. If the $35 price tag is too expensive, perhaps you can obtain the article via inter-library loan, which, since it is not a book, would hopefully be free (at least for paper journals)

Comment: Thanks! I will try that route but can afford that if not.

Comment: This site advertises a free download: https://www.academia.edu/50832070/Chrysostoms_Homily_on_the_Word_Koimeterion_and_on_the_Cross_A_Translation_and_Commentary ; don't know if it works or not.

Comment: Thanks! I wrote an answer that can be converted to community post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A paper that has an English translation:

- Brill: https://brill.com/view/journals/vc/76/1/article-p1_1.xml?language=en

A (now public domain) book with the Greek text:

- https://www.google.com/books/edition/Opera_Omnia/at_RAAAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22%CE%A0%CE%BF%CE%BB%CE%BB%CE%AC%CE%BA%CE%B9%CF%82+%E1%BC%90%CE%B6%CE%AE%CF%84%CE%B7%CF%83%CE%B1+%CF%80%CF%81%E1%BD%B8%CF%82+%E1%BC%90%CE%BC%CE%B1%CF%85%CF%84%CF%8C%CE%BD%22&pg=RA2-PA469&printsec=frontcover

Other online editions can be found by searching "Πολλάκις ἐζήτησα πρὸς ἐμαυτόν".

Further references include:

- https://www.fourthcentury.com/on-the-cemetery-and-the-cross/

Comment: I converted to Community Wiki to encourage future edits. Thanks!